# Change date value to input type date

Tags: jquery, html, date

I have a form that asks the start date and end date. Here's my code below:

```js
$('input[name="start"]').on('change', function(){
  var max_months = 3;
  var start = new Date($(this).val());
  var end = new Date(start.setMonth(start.getMonth() + max_months));
  $('input[name="end"]').val(end);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="date" name="start">
<input type="date" name ="end">
</form>
```

So if I am going to choose a date "02/02/2018". The end date will turn to "005/02/2018"

Comment: You can also use `end = end.toISOString().substring(0,10);` . before updating the value in the end input box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```js
$('input[name="start"]').on('change', function(){
    var max_months = 3;
    var start = new Date($(this).val());
    start.setMonth(start.getMonth() + max_months); /* Add 3 months */
    var day = ("0" + start.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (start.getMonth() + 1  )).slice(-2);
    var end = start.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
    $('input[name="end"]').val(end);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="date" name="start">
<input type="date" name ="end">
</form>
```